# AMPscript to format number field - syntax error somewhere

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've put this AMPscript into an email to format the number field that I'm pulling in.

`$%%=v(formatnumber(@%%Amount%%,"#,###")=%%`

`%%Amount%%` in the record I'm proofing is 26000.0

However, it's formatting like this in the proofed email:
`$%%=v(formatnumber(@26000.0,"#,###")=%%`

I'm sure it's a simple AMPscript error somewhere along the line.  But I can't see where.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` symbol is used to define the following text as a variable name in AMPscript.

It sounds like `Amount` is inside of your sendable DE, so you would not need the `@` symbol. Also since it is inline, you do not need the `%%`.

You also have a v() wrapper, but no closing parenthesis on the end, which is throwing a syntax error. This v() wrapper is actually not needed either. This is more for displaying ampscript variable values, etc.

Here are a couple ways I would try this:

`%%=FormatNumber(Amount,"#,###")=%%` - but this will throw an error if the sendable data does not have a field named 'Amount'
`%%=FormatNumber(AttributeValue("Amount"),"#,###")=%%` - will provide empty result instead of error on no field existing.
Or a more comprehensive approach to handle empty values:

```
%%[ SET @Amount = AttributeValue("Amount")
    IF NOT EMPTY(@Amount) THEN
      SET @FormatAmount = FormatNumber(@Amount,"#,###")
    ELSE
      RaiseError('No Amount Defined')
    ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@FormatAmount)=%%
```